# Dúvida ao gerar REST de retorno de procedure no jersey

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, rest, restful

Tenho um método onde o retorno dele é uma lista, baseado em uma execução de uma procedure no banco

```
 StoredProcedureQuery spq
                = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("PROCEDURE");
 ....
```

O retorno dessa consulta são alguns campos de uma tabela, e outros são campos calculados.
 E esse retorno eu disponibilizo em json

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
....
```

Pois bem, estou com um pequeno problema, o json gerado a partir dessa procedure é inválido, o jersey coloca chaves na frente e no fim, e nao dá nome aos campos, apenas os valores, exemplo de retorno:

```
   ["300", "ABCD", "Teste"]
```

Em outros chamadas eu converto o retorno da procedure em objeto

```
StoredProcedureQuery spq
                = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("PROCEDURE", MinhaClasse.class);
```

e funciona, porém desta vez, os retornos não são de campos no banco de dados, e sim alguns campos calculados, então não posso fazer isso.

Alguém sabe o que possa ser feito no meu caso?

Exemplo de Retorno Procedure:

-Nome e Código do Produto - OK, tenho na entidade
-Valor Total dos itens em estoque, Esse campo é calculado na procedure, não posso adicionar na Entidade.
Dentre outros campos calculados que ela retorna.

Comment: Como é esse retorno da procedure? Uma lista de string ou um objeto com os atributos preenchidos?

Comment: O retorno do método é um List, na consulta da Procedure me parece ser um HashMap que o StoredProcedureQuery devolve, tem o nome dos campos e os valores, mas na conversão para JSON, o jersey "ignora" os campos e joga apenas os valores.

Comment: Eu acredito que o conversor não está interpretando o retorno corretamente (está interpretando como se fosse uma lista e não como um HashMap). Então, pra ter certeza, tenta pegar os valores que são retornados na procedure e montar um objeto (ou lista de objetos, dependendo da situação) e tente ver se ele converte os valores corretamente com os nomes dos campos.

Comment: Na verdade eu estava enganado, o problema é que o retorno do StoredProcedureQuery já vem sem o nome dos campos, somente uma lista com os valores de retorno da procedure. alguma ideia do que eu possa fazer nesse caso?

Comment: Eu pensei em criar uma classe de retorno, porém tenho campos que nao sao da tabela, e o método obriga que seja um @Entity, senão lança uma exceção de Entidade não encontrada.